# phonegap local run android adb devices error

Tags: cordova

Hi all im running the following

```
M:\LocalDevelopment\PhoneGap\HelloWorldW>phonegap local build android
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
```

which runs fine, however, when I run the following I get an error

```
M:\LocalDevelopment\PhoneGap\HelloWorldW>phonegap local run android
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
[phonegap] trying to install app onto device
[phonegap] no device was found
[phonegap] trying to install app onto emulator
   [error] An error occurred while emulating/deploying the android project.
M:\LocalDevelopment\PhoneGap\HelloWorldW\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
            throw e;
              ^
Error executing "adb devices": 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.
```

Ive added this

```
C:\Users\me\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools
```

as an Enviromental variable but still the same.

can anyone help or is there another way to get to preview what I have created?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's probable that you don't have the `platform-tools` folder located in your path as well.

Your path should include:

`C:\Users\me\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\me\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools`

Comment: Also don't forget to exit the command line and open a new one again. Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

I've also facing this problem. I've set my path are correct but adb.exe file missing in C:\phonegap_project\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools.

download the adb.exe and place the above directory and open the cmd type the adb if you get the some information everything is correct.

download link
http://adbshell.com/download/download-adb-for-windows.html