# How to upload files on local folder wth angu

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have an ionic project and I want to test it on my device.
I've seen some tutorial and I id like this :

```
ionic platform add android
```

and then

```
ionic run android
```

but it opens the emulator and I cannot see my application.

My main goal is to  export it on my phone,in order to test it.

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you just want to test your app on an Android device?

Comment: yes I do want to test it on phone .I have the developer mode activated

Comment: Test the commands provided in the answer below. Happy to help further if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Run `ionic run android --device`

> Note: Be sure that USB-Debugging is enabled on your device in
>   developer options.

Also to make sure your device is authorised you can run:

`adb devices`

Comment: it says 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: This question on SO has varying solutions that may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045583/phonegap-local-run-android-adb-devices-error

Comment: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Yes but what are you tying into your terminal to cause this message?

Comment: Do you have Android `platform-tools`

Comment: you mean adt bundle?

Comment: Yes, do yu have the platform-tools in the sdk folder?